# Call controller method using controller as syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have two instances of the same controller "ControllerA" instantiated using `ng-controller` with `as` syntax inside of a wrapping controller:

```
<div ng-contrller="MainController">
    <div ng-controller="ControllerA as Ctrl1"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerA as Ctrl2"></div>
</div>
```

Now what i want to achieve is that i can call something like `Ctrl1.controllerFunction()` inside of the `MainController`. Normally I would use `$broadcast` and `$on` to achieve a similiar behaviour when there would not be two instances of the same controller, so i can't use it here. I also don't want to use `preventDefault` on the event object of the `$broadcast` because it would get too messy.

Comment: I can't think of a use case where you need to instantiate the same controller twice or have a parent controller depend on a 'child' controller. It sounds like you need to rethink your page using directives and components.

Comment: It's somehow complicated, yes. My use case is that I have a page consisting of different "views" (using `ng-show` currently). In one of that view the controller is placed in a modal dialog while on the other it is placed embedded on the page. Now when I want to load data within the controller (always in just one instance), I can't get that managed. Using `$broadcast`, both controllers will get active. I want to call a certain controller depending on the method of the parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do what you are asking. `Ctrl1` isn't defined in the scope of `MainController`, it's in a sub-scope. `Ctrl1` and `Ctrl2` aren't even in the same scopes as each other so there's no real reason why you need to use different names. Also you could have `ng-repeat` or `ng-if` creating and destroying `ControllerA` instances so the lifetimes may be shorter than for `MainController`.

A better way to handle this would be to invert the responsiblities and make `ControllerA` instances register with `MainController` when created and de-register when destroyed. If you use controllerAs syntax also for `MainController` then it is easy for the child controllers to call methods on MainController.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as Main">
    <div ng-controller="ControllerA as Ctrl1" ng-init="Ctrl1.init('Ctrl1')"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerA as Ctrl2" ng-init="Ctrl2.init('Ctrl2')"></div>
</div>

function ControllerA($scope) {
    const vm = this;
    vm.init = function(name) {
        $scope.Main.register(name, vm);
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $scope.Main.deregister(name);
        });
    }
}
```

You then write suitable `register` and `deregister` functions in `MainController` to keep track of the child controllers. Something like:

```
function MainController() {
    const vm = this;
    const children = {};
    vm.register = function(name, vm) { children[name] = vm; }
    vm.deregister = function(name) { delete children[name]; }

   // ... and now you can do 
    if (children.Ctrl1) children.Ctrl1.controllerFunction();
}
```

You might instead put the init method in `MainController` but that would make de-registration difficult as you need the child scope.

Comment: Am I guessing right that i could use `$scope.Ctrl1.method()` in the `MainController`? I am not familiar with that register and deregister method nor can I find anything in the docs about that.

Comment: No, `MainController`'s scope cannot reference `Ctrl1` as that is in a child scope, but the child controllers can reference the parent scopes. The intention is that you write `register` and `deregister` functions to keep track of the child scopes.